# Is there a material that I could use to generate cap touch presses?

Tags: capacitive, touchscreen, touch-panel, user-interface

I want to automate some testing that uses captouch as the interface for the human user. I would love to use an Arduino or similar's GPIO to create the equivalent press and release events from a finger. Is there some material that can be used here such that it would cause a press event when I set the GPIO to high? I would like to avoid any mechanical solutions that involve moving things. Ideally, I would tape the material onto the place where the button is and run my fake human code on the Arduino.

Had a hard time wording that, hope it makes sense. Also, I'm pretty ignorant with the electronics for a captouch system given that I'm a software guy...be gentle :pray:

Comment: This sort of question is asked over and over again. Try searching this site for the word "touch".

Comment: @ElliotAlderson you're my hero. My Google-fu failed me. I'ma see if I can get with my hardware guy and try this out. Will post that link as the solution or put up some data when I do.

Comment: In addition to the other answer, trying to do this isn't all that reliable.